# Google spreadsheet query formula - join like

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-query-language

I got this case:

```
A; B; C; D
a; 3; b; 4
e; 6;  ;  
b; 5; c; 6
c; 4; a; 2
d; 5
```

I would like to build:

```
E; F; G
a; 3; 2
b; 5; 4
c; 4; 6
d;  ; 5
e; 6;
```

I tried some queries without sucess and didn't found a join simple solution... Can you help me to find a solution please ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this formula in cell E1:

`=SORT(UNIQUE(QUERY({A:A;C:C},"where Col1 <> ''")),1,1)`

and then this formula in cell F1 and dragged down the column:

`=TRANSPOSE(QUERY({A:B;C:D},"select Col2 where Col1='"&E1&"'"))`

See this example sheet to see these working: https://goo.gl/sv8ViD

Also, it is possible to create the output in a single cell (see cell Q1) but the formula is not very adaptable

Comment: Woaw, great, thanks a lot for answer. Trying to make it work with the "real" case ;)